# Problem with FlashBuilder

Tags: flash-builder

I a bigginer to this FlashBuilder, i have developed an application, but when i want to run the app, an error "`Unbale to resolve resource bundle "containers: for locale en_US`" is showing, eventhough i did not configure any locales to my appl. My Flex Compiler shows only `-locale en_US`. Please help ?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely loading a resource bundle called 'containers' but it cannot find the properties file for it. You will have to add a Source Path in project properties --> Flex Build Path under the 'Source Path' tab.  I have bundles{locale} as one of my paths. Then create a bundles folder with containers.properties in it.  It should then be able to find the file.